# SQL-запрос Получить значения неповторяющихся значений

Tags: mysql

Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос. 
Мне необходимо получить сумму цен всех значений, где id не повторяется

Допустим

```
id|price|status
1 | 2   | 1
2 | 3   | 1
2 | 3   | 1
3 | 3   | 1
4 | 3   | 4
```

В итоге должно получится сумма цен статусов с уникальными id.

```
status|summ|
 1    | 8  |
 4    | 3  |
```

Делаю GROUP BY status. Но не могу рядом написать GROUP BY id. 
Может как-то через DISTINCT можно?

Comment: Как быть с одинаковыми id для разных статусов? (id, status) - (2, 1), (2,2)

Comment: Надо считать сумму price, а не id.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что такое

> В итоге должно получится сумма статусов с уникальными id.

Но к приведенному результату, приведет такой запрос

```sql
SELECT
  status,
  SUM(id) AS summ
FROM
  my_table
GROUP BY
  status
```

Comment: Привел в примере. id=2 повторяется 2 раза .
т.е. сумма статуса 1 должна получится 8. У статуса 4 сумма=3. Ваш sql даст в статусе 1 сумму равную 11.

Comment: @РадикКамалов Извините, но я опять ничего не понял. Ну хорошо, id=2 повторяется 2 раза. Но почему "сумма статуса 1 должна получится 8"? Что такое **сумма статуса** и откуда 8? `Ваш sql даст в статусе 1 сумму равную 11` - чушь! Получится 8

Comment: Надо считать price, а не id.